# How do I change state on dropdown select in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

for a bit of context I'm trying to make a component navigation menu for my react app. Essentially each dropdown value is equivalent to some components. The way I was going to do this is like follows:

Dropdown menu

```
<form>
            <label htmlFor="#endpointSelect">Endpoint:</label><br/>
            <select value={moduleValue} id="endpointSelect" onChange={() => activateModuleValue()}>
                <option value="1"> Latest </option>
                <option value="2"> Convert </option>
                <option value="3"> Historical </option>
                <option value="4"> Time Series </option>
                <option value="5"> Fluctuation </option>
                <option value="6"> Carat </option>
                <option value="7"> Lowest-Highest </option>
             </select>
          </form>
```

And this is the `activateModuleValue()`

```
const [module, setModule] = useState();

// set the module value
  const activateModuleValue = () => {

    console.log(moduleValue);

  }
```

Eventually there will be a method with a bunch of if statements indicating  `1 = <Latest/>, 2 = <Convert/>, etc.`

What I was having issues with is correctly grabbing the option values. Using onChange in general I've noticed it returns the value FROM the element I'm changing from instead of changing TO.

Another approach that I'm currently trying is using the `value={moduleValue}`. Essentially on dropdown select the `moduleValue` state should change, and ideally I'd have something along the lines of:

```
useEffect(() => {
        activateModule();
    }, [moduleValue]);
```

Where the intent would be to call on the "setActiveComponenet" method whenever the state for `moduleValue` changes

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my own question, you have to first set the state and then separately associate state with a component:

```
// set the module value
  const activateModuleValue = (e) => {
    setModuleValue(e)
  }

  // set the module
  const activateModule = () => {
    if(moduleValue == 1){
      setModule(<Latest/>)
    }
```